# DimpleJS chart with multiple series

Tags: dimple.js

I'm trying to draw a chart with multiple lines, but as not every series on it has the same time coordinates, one of the lines is drawn scattered, with points not connected.

You can see what I'm trying to explain here: [My chart](http://www.fedea.net/pymes-morosidad/index_test.html)

When dates changes using the provided slider, the 'Previsiones' input or even clicking over the lines, you can see how lines redraw.

And here's the data I'm using:

```
[{ "Fecha": "01-Jan-14","Dato": 13.53,"Tipo": "Previsión"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Feb-14","Dato": 13.49,"Tipo": "Previsión"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Mar-14","Dato": 13.77,"Tipo": "Previsión"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Apr-14","Dato": 13.93,"Tipo": "Previsión"},
{ "Fecha": "01-May-14","Dato": 13.94,"Tipo": "Previsión"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jun-14","Dato": 14.09,"Tipo": "Previsión"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jan-14","Dato": 13.53,"Tipo": "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Nov-10","Dato": 5.68,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Dec-10","Dato": 5.81,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jan-11","Dato": 6.06,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Feb-11","Dato": 6.19,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Mar-11","Dato": 6.11,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Apr-11","Dato": 6.36,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-May-11","Dato": 6.49,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jun-11","Dato": 6.69,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jul-11","Dato": 6.94,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Aug-11","Dato": 7.15,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Sep-11","Dato": 7.16,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Oct-11","Dato": 7.42,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Nov-11","Dato": 7.51,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Dec-11","Dato": 7.61,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jan-12","Dato": 7.91,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Feb-12","Dato": 8.27,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Mar-12","Dato": 8.37,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Apr-12","Dato": 8.72,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-May-12","Dato": 8.96,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jun-12","Dato": 9.65,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jul-12","Dato": 9.86,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Aug-12","Dato": 10.51,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Sep-12","Dato": 10.71,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Oct-12","Dato": 11.23,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Nov-12","Dato": 11.38,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Dec-12","Dato": 10.44,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jan-13","Dato": 10.78,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Feb-13","Dato": 10.4,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Mar-13","Dato": 10.47,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Apr-13","Dato": 10.88,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-May-13","Dato": 11.22,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jun-13","Dato": 11.63,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jul-13","Dato": 11.98,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Aug-13","Dato": 12.14,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Sep-13","Dato": 12.67,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Oct-13","Dato": 13,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Nov-13","Dato": 13.07,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Dec-13","Dato": 13.61,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha": "01-Jan-14","Dato": 13.53,"Tipo": "Dato Observado"}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: This is a better dataset to understand the problem. Basically is any date presentation in between first and last.

```
[{ "Fecha" : "01-Dec-12", "Dato" : 10.44, "tipo" : "Previsión" },
{ "Fecha" : "01-Jan-13", "Dato" : 10.21, "tipo" : "Previsión" },
{ "Fecha" : "01-Feb-13", "Dato" : 10.16, "tipo" : "Previsión" },
{ "Fecha" : "01-Mar-13", "Dato" : 9.57, "tipo" : "Previsión" },
{ "Fecha" : "01-Apr-13", "Dato" : 9.53, "tipo" : "Previsión" },
{ "Fecha" : "01-May-13", "Dato" : 9.5, "tipo" : "Previsión" },
{ "Fecha" : "01-Dec-12", "Dato" : 10.44, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Jan-13", "Dato" : 10.78, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Feb-13", "Dato" : 10.4, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Mar-13", "Dato" : 10.47, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Apr-13", "Dato" : 10.88, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-May-13", "Dato" : 11.22, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Jun-13", "Dato" : 11.63, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Jul-13", "Dato" : 11.98, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Aug-13", "Dato" : 12.14, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Sep-13", "Dato" : 12.67, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Oct-13", "Dato" : 13, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Nov-13", "Dato" : 13.07, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Dec-13", "Dato" : 13.61, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Jan-14", "Dato" : 13.53, "tipo" : "Dato Observado (futuro)"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Nov-10", "Dato" : 5.68, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Dec-10", "Dato" : 5.81, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Jan-11", "Dato" : 6.06, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Feb-11", "Dato" : 6.19, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Mar-11", "Dato" : 6.11, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Apr-11", "Dato" : 6.36, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-May-11", "Dato" : 6.49, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Jun-11", "Dato" : 6.69, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Jul-11", "Dato" : 6.94, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Aug-11", "Dato" : 7.15, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Sep-11", "Dato" : 7.16, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Oct-11", "Dato" : 7.42, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Nov-11", "Dato" : 7.51, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Dec-11", "Dato" : 7.61, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Jan-12", "Dato" : 7.91, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Feb-12", "Dato" : 8.27, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Mar-12", "Dato" : 8.37, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Apr-12", "Dato" : 8.72, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-May-12", "Dato" : 8.96, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Jun-12", "Dato" : 9.65, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Jul-12", "Dato" : 9.86, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Aug-12", "Dato" : 10.51, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Sep-12", "Dato" : 10.71, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Oct-12", "Dato" : 11.23, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Nov-12", "Dato" : 11.38, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"},
{ "Fecha" : "01-Dec-12", "Dato" : 10.44, "tipo" : "Dato Observado"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice graphic! If I understand correctly your issue is with the missing connecting line in some charts.  I think this is a bug with the line re-drawing in dimple.  I suggest you clear and redraw the chart every time, it should render quick enough to not be a problem.  I've recreated your chart in a fiddle here and it seems to render fine:

`Example in question:` http://jsfiddle.net/T6ZDL/6/

Having said that, that example seems ok in your original page.  Do you have a dataset for one of the views which fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot on your quick response. I'm editing my question, adding problematic dataset.

Comment: Great! As you suggested, I clear and redraw the chart every time. Now it is rendering normal. Thank you very much!

Comment: No, problem.  It's a really nice use of dimple.